# compiling data from many lists

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have 4 instances of `List<InputElement>` which contain time-value pair, looking like this

```
public class InputElement
{
        public MyTime Time;
        public double Value;
}
```

`MyTime` holds time in format: hh:mm:ss.uuuuu - like `TimeSpan` but with microseconds and also stores `double TotalSeconds` - which shows, well, total time in seconds (for example `00:01:02.00304 = 62.00034`) which I used for sorting lists

Each list is loaded already sorted by time from earliest to latest moment and stores different value types. So `List1` holds measures of speed, `List2` holds distances and so on. The length of all lists is about 200 elements

I want to put all 4 of them in one `List<OutputElement>` where `OutputElement` looks like:

```
public class OutputElement
    {
        public MyTime Time;

        public double Dp;
        public double Or;
        public double Speed;
        public double Dist;
    }
```

Problem is - values can be in different and in same moments, so the result should look something like this:

```
mt1      1    NaN    NaN    NaN
mt2    NaN      3      2    NaN
mt3      2      7    NaN    NaN
mt4      3      6      1      0
```

Here in moment `mt1` I save only `Dp` value, because three other lists don't contain value at that moment, so three other values are `NaN`. While in moment `mt4` I have all four `DataElements`, because all four lists contain value at that moment.

I tried to go direct path - created endless `while` loop cycling through four lists using four counters

Each cycle after a lot of `if` cases I find which counters to increase and what to save. After cycling through all lists I break the `while` loop and exit.

All this looks like combinatorical hellhole and I would really appreciate simpler approach?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dictionary using the mt as the key and an OutputElement as the value. When iterating your lists, look to see if the dictionary's key collection contains a the mt value. If so then get the corresponding OutputElement and set the members as needed. If the dictionary's key collection does not have the mt value, create a new OutputElement instance, set the required members and add it to the dictionary.

As far as the iteration of the lists, you could either iterate each list independently, or you could get the number of items in the longest list and loop up to that number. If doing the latter, you just need to making sure the index variable does not exceed the number of items in the list.